# Subdivision Surface on Cylinder

Tags: modeling, subdivision-surface

I'm trying to subdivide this cylinder to give it more definition:

[image: Low poly]

And to look as close as possible to this:

[image: High poly]

(To achieve this I first applied the Subdivision modifier and then moved the edges on position)

But when I try to Crease the selected edges (first image) to make them sharper, they are distorted like this causing a shading issue that doesn't look good on outer faces of the cylinder

[image: The problem]

What is the best way to do this without having to move the edges manually?

Comment: Hi :). You're gonna need more geometry, to support these details. In this case perhaps a hardsurface workflow with bevel modifier might be more appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can afford a bit more vertices, like 32 vertex cylinder, you can try this topology:

[image]

[image]

It's easier with 64 vertex cylinder:

[image]

Comment: I think that's the best option I have. 
I was trying to create a high poly version but I encountered a lot of problems with the bake, I guess the low poly version have too few polygons than necessary.

Comment: yes I guess sometimes you have no other choice but increase the topology a bit